# How to write own java function in Visual rules BRM?

Tags: rule-engine

We are using Visual rules BRM powered by actico to manage Business rules.There are many builtin function provided by visual rules library. Now I want to add a custom function to my project. How can I do this. I'm new in this. Thanks In advance. I'm using 6.4 version visual rules run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a Java class and define a required method in class then go on function package and right click and follow steps below:-
->New Element, -> function, ->Check (import from java method) ->Next, -> (browse your java class and method -> finish)

Answer (score 2):

Create a method in java class then Right click on project>>new element>>function>>import from java method>>choose the package>>select method and finish.